# How to remove/hide the "featured video" from a YouTube embed?

Tags: youtube

If you have activated the [featured video](https://www.youtube.com/featured_content) option in YouTube, there will be a little banner to the end of each video. Example:

[image: screen shot of featured video]

How to disable this from the embed, but leave it alive on the YouTube page?

I could not find the option in the [YouTube embed parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Comment: Update: Got it working by `iv_load_policy=3`. Obviously you have to disable annotations and this disables the featured video as well. (June 2015)

Comment: Since you figured out how to do it, [you can answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Update: Got it working by adding the URL parameter `iv_load_policy=3`. Obviously you have to disable annotations and this disables the featured video as well.